# Getting value of anchor tag on document ready from a page in jquery from other than using id attr

Tags: jquery

I want to get a value from anchor tag on the document ready function and i dont want to use the id attr. Suggest some method to retrieve values using name attr on document ready from a anchor tag using jquery?

Comment: there is no `value` to Anchors... -1 + not a real question + flag.

Comment: It would be easier to suggest something if we could see your markup. Can you also clarify what value you want to gather from the anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`attribute-equals`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector, like so:

```
$('a[name="whatever"]')
```

Once you've selected the relevant anchor element(s) then you can call whatever jQuery functions you need to retrieve the required information.

Comment: are you sure `name` is a valid attribute for anchor? **Update:** Yes it is but _"Anchor name. Obsolete in HTML5"_

Comment: @gdoron I'm not sure it's a valid attribute, no. However, [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rswb5/) indicates it will work in FF13, IE9 and Chrome19.

Comment: It will work in new browsers with every attribute. I would have upvote the answer if the question was a real one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of any attribute using jQuery attr(), for example:

```
$('a').attr('name');
```

I'd suggest using HTML5's data attribute instead of name:

```
<a href="#" data-some-attribute="somevalue"></a>

$('a').data('some-attribute');
```

Comment: to be precise i am working in java. I hav a table which populates various data and their is a column called actions which is used to edit or delete the data. I am also doing this page according to w3c standards so i cant have same id for the delete link. So how can i get the required value at document on ready if cant use the same id?

Comment: Add the unique value to the data attribute

Comment: thank you all for your comments. i took it using ($('a[name="delLink"]')) where delLink is name attribute.